# How do I use C# to get the Hard-disk serial number?

Tags: c#, windows-vista, hard-drive

How do i get the hard disk serial number without using dll and supported by VISTA

Answer (score 14):

```
using System.Management;

public string GetHDDSerial()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");

    foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
    {
        // get the hardware serial no.
        if (wmi_HD["SerialNumber"] != null)
            return wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString();
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

here is the code that work's for me :

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = null;
 searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

 foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
 {
     HardDrive hd = new HardDrive();

     try
     {  
         txtmdl.Text = hd.Caption = wmi_HD["Caption"].ToString();
         txtsn.Text=(hd.SerialNo = wmi_HD.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumber").ToString());
```

i just added 2 textBox's to get the results ,, you can do the same !

and the hard drive class :

```
public class HardDrive
        {
            public string Model { get; set; }
            public string InterfaceType { get; set; }
            public string Caption { get; set; }
            public string SerialNo { get; set; }
        }
```

Don't forget to use :

```
using System.Management;
```

Source :
[get serial number of hard disk in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676105/get-serial-number-of-2-hard-disks-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120423074747/http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1732.htm) and let us know if it works:

```
// Namespace Reference
using System.Management;

/// <summary>
/// method to retrieve the selected HDD's serial number
/// </summary>
/// <param name="strDriveLetter">Drive letter to retrieve serial number for</param>
/// <returns>the HDD's serial number</returns>
public string GetHDDSerialNumber(string drive)
{
    //check to see if the user provided a drive letter
    //if not default it to "C"
    if (drive == "" || drive == null)
    {
        drive = "C";
    }
    //create our ManagementObject, passing it the drive letter to the
    //DevideID using WQL
    ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"" + drive +":\"");
    //bind our management object
    disk.Get();
    //return the serial number
    return disk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();
}
```

EDIT: And if that doesn't work, try this code from the [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/hard_disk_serialno.aspx):

> First, let's create a class to store information about a hard drive:

```
class HardDrive
{
 private string model = null;
 private string type = null;
 private string serialNo = null; 
 public string Model
 {
  get {return model;}
  set {model = value;}
 } 
 public string Type
 {
  get {return type;}
  set {type = value;}
 } 
 public string SerialNo
 {
  get {return serialNo;}
  set {serialNo = value;}
 }
}
```

> Next, we query the Win32_DiskDrive class:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
 ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

foreach(ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
{
 HardDrive hd = new HardDrive();
 hd.Model = wmi_HD["Model"].ToString();
 hd.Type  = wmi_HD["InterfaceType"].ToString();
 hdCollection.Add(hd);
}
```

> Now we need to extract the serial number from the Win32_PhysicalMedia
>   class:

```
searcher = new
 ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");

int i = 0;
foreach(ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
{
 // get the hard drive from collection
 // using index
 HardDrive hd = (HardDrive)hdCollection[i];

 // get the hardware serial no.
 if (wmi_HD["SerialNumber"] == null)
  hd.SerialNo = "None";
 else
  hd.SerialNo = wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString();

 ++i;
}
```

> Now we display our hard drive's information:

```
// Display available hard drives
foreach(HardDrive hd in hdCollection)
{
 Console.WriteLine("Model\t\t: " + hd.Model);
 Console.WriteLine("Type\t\t: " + hd.Type);
 Console.WriteLine("Serial No.\t: " + hd.SerialNo);
 Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi just found this link

It worked for me:

[enter link description here](http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20030511.asp)

Herre is the essential part of the code:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// return Volume Serial Number from hard drive
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="strDriveLetter">[optional] Drive letter</param>
  /// <returns>[string] VolumeSerialNumber</returns>
  public string GetVolumeSerial(string strDriveLetter)
  {
      if( strDriveLetter=="" || strDriveLetter==null) 
          strDriveLetter="C";
     ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"" + strDriveLetter +":\"");
     disk.Get();
     return disk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();
  }
```