# Get HDD serial over shared path

Tags: c#, kernel32, shared-directory

I have a C# win form app. In it I'm getting a unique serial of HDD by using this method.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool GetVolumeInformation(string Volume, StringBuilder VolumeName,
            uint VolumeNameSize, out uint SerialNumber, uint SerialNumberLength,
            uint flags, StringBuilder fs, uint fs_size);
```

with Volume variable as `Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.CurrentDirectory)`

I get the serial as `SerialNumber.ToString("X")`

Works fine but the situation is;

1. I have Shared the app folder. I get `XXXXXXXX` as serial when I run the `EXE`
2. When another person run the app from my shared path he gets `00000000` as serial
3. But when that another user **Mapped** this folder and run the app he gets `XXXXXXXX` as serial

So what is the cause of this problem? Is there any better way to use?

I referred [WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353881/how-do-i-use-c-sharp-to-get-the-hard-disk-serial-number) but didn't fit to my need.

Comment: Just a guess, but I'd assume that if you use an UNC path as Volume (something like "\\Server\Share\app.exe"), then this does not work, because the share is not really a volume that has a serial number. If you map it, it becomes a drive letter and gets a serial number. Is the serial number the same when run locally as when run using the mapped path?

Comment: @PMF Yes it is same..

Comment: That surprises me a bit, because that means it doesn't need to be unique. If you have several mappings from different shares of the same machine, you'd get duplicate serials.

Comment: @PMF I add two mapping drives to same folder. both gave same serial..

Comment: Ok, that confirms my assumption. It really says that the volume serial number is not necessarily unique. Depending on what you're trying to do, this might or might not be a problem.